# how to export and import sqlite table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm working on an an app that contain sqlite table with multiple columns , so we can add items to the table and displayed in listview then each item has it's own details that could be displayed in a detail activity, how to export and import the data from the sqlite table ?

display products [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjsbA.png)

detail activity [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToXy4.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different methods, but here's how I did it for a pedometer app I made.

First, you should write all the SQL queries that you will need and put them in a class as constants so that you can use them easily later on.

```
public class StepCountTable {

    private StepCountTable() {}

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_SQL =
            "CREATE TABLE STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE" +
            "(" +
            "    ID             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "    STEP_COUNT     INTEGER," +
            "    DAY            INTEGER" +
            ")";

    public static final String DROP_TABLE_SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE";

    public static final String SELECT_ALL =
            "SELECT\n" +
            "    ID,\n" +
            "    STEP_COUNT,\n" +
            "    DAY\n" +
            "FROM\n" +
            "    STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE";

    public static final String SELECT_BY_ID =
            "SELECT\n" +
            "    ID\n" +
            "    STEP_COUNT\n" +
            "    DAY\n" +
            "FROM" +
            "   STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE\n" +
            "WHERE\n" +
            "   ID = ?"; // ? represents parameters to be added later

    public static final String SELECT_BY_DATE =
            "SELECT\n" +
            "    SUM(STEP_COUNT) SUM_STEP_COUNT,\n" +
            "    DAY\n" +
            "FROM\n" +
            "    STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE\n" +
            "GROUP BY \n" +
            "    DAY";

    public static final String SELECT_FROM_DATE =
            "SELECT \n" +
            "    SUM(STEP_COUNT) SUM_STEP_COUNT,\n" +
            "    DAY\n" +
            "FROM " +
            "    STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE\n" +
            "WHERE " +
            "    DAY >= ? AND " +
            "    DAY <= ? " +
            "GROUP BY \n" +
            "    DAY";

    public static final String INSERT =
            "INSERT INTO STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE" +
            "(" +
            "   STEP_COUNT," +
            "   DAY" +
            ")" +
            "VALUES" +
            "(" +
            "   ?," +
            "   ?" +
            ")";

    public static final String UPDATE =
            "UPDATE\n" +
            "    STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE\n" +
            "SET\n" +
            "    STEP_COUNT = ?,\n" +
            "    DAY = ?\n" +
            "WHERE\n" +
            "    ID = ?;";

    public static final String DELETE_ALL_BEFORE_DATE =
            "DELETE FROM\n" +
            "    STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE\n" +
            "WHERE\n" +
            "    DAY < ?;";

    public static final String DELETE_ALL = "DELETE FROM STEP_COUNT_BY_DATE";

    public static final String SELECT_ID_SQL = "SELECT last_insert_rowid()";
}
```

You should also have a class that represents each table to store data retrieved from the database or data to be added to the database.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class StepCount {

    private long id;
    private Date date;
    private int stepCount;

    public StepCount(long id, int stepCount, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.stepCount = stepCount;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getStringFormatedDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return dateFormat.format(this.date);
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getStepCount() {
        return stepCount;
    }
}
```

After that, you need a repository for this table that will handle all the necessary operations to execute each query.

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Repository<T> {
    void create(T item);
    T readById(Long id);
    List<T> readAll();
    void update(T item);
    void delete();
}
```

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;

public class StepCountRepository implements Repository<StepCount> {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public StepCountRepository(SQLiteDatabase pedometerDatabase) {
        this.database = pedometerDatabase;
    }

    @Override
    public void create(StepCount stepCount) {
        if (stepCount == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        Calendar dateOfCreation = new GregorianCalendar();
        dateOfCreation.setTime(stepCount.getDate());
        dateOfCreation.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        dateOfCreation.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        dateOfCreation.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        dateOfCreation.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        database.beginTransaction();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = database.rawQuery(StepCountTable.INSERT, new String[]{
                    Integer.toString(stepCount.getStepCount()),
                    Long.toString(dateOfCreation.getTimeInMillis())
            });

            cursor.moveToNext();
            cursor.close();

            cursor = database.rawQuery(StepCountTable.SELECT_ID_SQL, new String[]{});
            cursor.moveToNext();

            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            stepCount.setId(id);

            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Unable to create stepCount.", e);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) cursor.close();
        }

        database.endTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public StepCount readById(Long id) {
        StepCount stepCount = null;

        try (Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                StepCountTable.SELECT_BY_ID,
                new String[]{
                        String.valueOf(id)
                }
        )) {
            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("STEP_COUNT"));
                Date date = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("DAY")));

                stepCount = new StepCount(id, count, date);
            }
        }
        return stepCount;
    }

    @Override
    public List<StepCount> readAll() {
        List<StepCount> stepCounts = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                StepCountTable.SELECT_ALL,
                new String[]{}
        )) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("STEP_COUNT"));
                Date date = new Date((cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("DAY"))));

                stepCounts.add(new StepCount(id, count, date));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Unable to read stepCount", e);
        }

        return stepCounts;
    }

    public List<StepCount> readFromDate(Date dateFrom) {
        List<StepCount> stepCounts = new ArrayList<>();
        Date today = new Date();
        today.setSeconds(59);
        today.setMinutes(59);
        today.setHours(23);

        Calendar dateToReadFrom = new GregorianCalendar();
        dateToReadFrom.setTime(dateFrom);
        dateToReadFrom.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        dateToReadFrom.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        dateToReadFrom.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        dateToReadFrom.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        try (Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                StepCountTable.SELECT_FROM_DATE,
                new String[]{
                        Long.toString(dateToReadFrom.getTimeInMillis() + 1),
                        Long.toString(today.getTime())
                }
        )) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long id = -1L;
                int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("SUM_STEP_COUNT"));
                Date date = new Date((cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("DAY"))));

                stepCounts.add(new StepCount(id, count, date));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Unable to read stepCount", e);
        }

        return stepCounts;
    }

    public List<StepCount> readAllByDate() {
        List<StepCount> stepCounts = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                StepCountTable.SELECT_BY_DATE,
                new String[]{}
        )) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("SUM_STEP_COUNT"));
                Date date = new Date((cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("DAY"))));

                stepCounts.add(new StepCount(0, count, date));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Unable to read stepCount", e);
        }

        return stepCounts;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(StepCount stepCount) {
        database.beginTransaction();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = database.rawQuery(StepCountTable.UPDATE, new String[]{
                    Integer.toString(stepCount.getStepCount()),
                    Long.toString(stepCount.getDate().getTime()),
                    Long.toString(stepCount.getId())
            });

            cursor.moveToNext();
            cursor.close();

            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Unable to update StepCount.", e);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) cursor.close();
        }

        database.endTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete() {
        database.beginTransaction();

        try (Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                StepCountTable.DELETE_ALL,
                new String[]{}
        )) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            cursor.close();

            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Unable de delete StepCounts.", e);
        }

        database.endTransaction();
    }

    public void delete(Date date) {
        database.beginTransaction();

        Calendar dateToDeleteFrom = new GregorianCalendar();
        dateToDeleteFrom.setTime(date);
        dateToDeleteFrom.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        dateToDeleteFrom.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        dateToDeleteFrom.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        dateToDeleteFrom.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


        try (Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                StepCountTable.DELETE_ALL_BEFORE_DATE,
                new String[]{
                        Long.toString(dateToDeleteFrom.getTimeInMillis())
                }
        )) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            cursor.close();

            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Unable to delete StepCounts.", e);
        }

        database.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

To get a connection to your database, you will need to make a Factory class that implements SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class PedometerDatabaseFactory extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Pedometer.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public PedometerDatabaseFactory(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(StepCountTable.CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        database.execSQL(StepCountTable.DROP_TABLE_SQL);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

Now, to use it, you would do something like this in your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PedometerDatabaseFactory pedometerDatabaseFactory;
    private StepCountRepository stepCountRepository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pedometerDatabaseFactory = new PedometerDatabaseFactory(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        stepCountRepository = new StepCountRepository(
                pedometerDatabaseFactory.getWritableDatabase()
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        pedometerDatabaseFactory.close();
    }
}
```

You will need to execute the queries in AsyncTasks though, so you have to pass your repository to the AsyncTask.

**MainActivity:**

```
private void fetchAllStepsCountByDate() {
    new FetchAllStepsCountByDateAsyncTask(
            this::onStepsCountByDateFound,
            this::OnNoAccessError,
            stepCountRepository
    ).execute();
}
```

**FetchAllStepsCountByDateAsyncTask:**

```
@Override
protected Promise<List<StepCount>, DatabaseError> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    List<StepCount> stepCountDataSet;

    try {
        stepCountDataSet = stepCountRepository.readAllByDate();
        return Promise.ok(stepCountDataSet);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Promise.err(DatabaseError.NO_ACCESS);
    }
}
```